# Jquery Highlight Active Link works for Href links but not Menu Items

Tags: jquery, asp.net, menu, highlighting

I am using an asp menu control like so. And I'd like to highlight the currently active menu

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
     Orientation="Horizontal">          
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Home.aspx" Text="Home" />
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="EventMGMT.aspx" Text="Event Management" />
       </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
```

This Jquery works for a href links but doesnt work for my menu control. What do I have to do so that it references my menu url's

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $("#NavMenu").find("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass("selected");
    });
```

edit: is this possible with pure css?

Comment: This is a 100% client-side issue, so please show your HTML output, not your ASP server-side code.

Comment: this is all my code, html output is just your standard navigation bar, this isn't going to be a real website, will only be run locally

Comment: It seems you don't know the difference between HTML and .NET source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Menu client id when you get it on client. Try using the following code snippet:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.href;
            url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            $("#" + "<%= NavMenu.ClientID %>").find("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass("selected");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this didn't work, like i said to diodeus this is only going to be running locally on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
 inside menu control
<staticselectedstyle backcolor="red" />

 inside css
   div.menu ul li a::selection
    {

     }
```